# PHP/MySQL Select all rows from table and display the column value with lowest value

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to run an SQL Query to select all rows from a table and then display the column with the lowest value for each row.

for example, lets start with row1...

```
columns1, column2, column3, column4
```

the lowest value for this row is in `column3` so i need to echo the `column3` value then on `row2`, `column4` has the lowest value so `column4` should be displayed for this row.

i did try this code:

```
$sql="SELECT * from callplanmeta ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    $sql2="SELECT *, MIN(NULLIF(".$result["callplanname"].",0)) as number2 from callplandata ";
    echo $sql2;
    $rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
    while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2))
    {
        echo $result2["description"].' - '.number_format($result2["number2"],2).'<br><br>';
    }
}
```

however i then realised that it was doing it the wrong way round and only showing the lowest value for 1 row

the column names in the `callplandata` table match the column `callplanname` in the `callplanmeta` table

the columns in the `callplandata` table are dynamic so they are changing all the time and more are constantly being added

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Display lowest number from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18301749/php-display-lowest-number-from-database)

Comment: I would say if you are dynamically adding columns to your table, that you need to look at normalizing that table and having those columns as row values on perhaps a many-to-many join table.

Answer (score 0):

First you will use this

```
SELECT 
        GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
FROM 
        INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE 
        table_name = 'mytable'
AND 
        ORDINAL_POSITION>2
```

To retrieve all columns, form it as a string in PHP and then run the following (col1,col2,col3) needs to be replaced with the column_name string that you can form using the previous query.

PHP Code added

From your code I understand two things, first you dont need a while loop for the first query because it would return only one record and you need a while loop for the second query because it would return multiple rows, let me try to make up the code accordingly

```
<?php 

$field_string= $mysqli->query("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME) AS field_string
               FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
               WHERE table_name = `callplandata`
               AND ORDINAL_POSITION>2")->fetch_object()->field_string;
```

(The >2 above means this will ignore the first two columns, which in your case seems to be number, description. IF you have more or less fields to be ignored then you can modify this number accordingly)

You can then use this field_string value into your other query that needs to find the least

```
$sql2="SELECT LEAST(".$field_string.") AS number FROM `callplandata`"; 

$rs2=mysql_query($sql2,$conn); 

while($result2=mysql_fetch_array($rs2)) 
{ 
   echo $result2["number"].'<br>'; 
} 
?>
```

This will give you the lowest among all the columns other than the first two columns for all the rows and echo it on screen. I am not a PHP programmer, so just about made up the code in PHP, there could be minor errors.

Comment: ee my edit: the columns in the callplandata table are dynamic so they are changing all the time and more are constantly being added

Comment: So you say you want the minimum of all columns in a table?

Comment: I am sorry if I did not understand, does that mean your query is answered or I just understood the question :)

Comment: did we deal with this in a different question? I think you need to use PHP in between properly to get this to work...

Comment: I have copied and pasted the answer from the other questions,  I am marking this as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

you can also get result with this

SELECT Id, 
  CASE WHEN COLUMN1 <= COLUMN2 and COLUMN1 <= COLUMN3 THEN COLUMN1
       WHEN COLUMN2 <= COLUMN1 and COLUMN2 <= COLUMN3 THEN COLUMN2
       ELSE COLUMN3 END AS smallest
FROM table_name

you can get result for any number of columns.

Comment: ee my edit: the columns in the callplandata table are dynamic so they are changing all the time and more are constantly being added

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this puzzle this approach:

```
SELECT

(SELECT columns1 from myTable) as myField

UNION 
(SELECT column2 from myTable)

UNION 
(SELECT column3 from myTable)

order by myField ASC LIMIT 1
```